Is there a way to restrict stack traces from emitting dataframe contents?
By default, our system logs stack traces in logs output. Generally, we're careful to not log contents of dataframes we're working with as they may contain sensitive user data. However, when Dask crashes, it seems to emit a sample of the dataframe it was working with:
2024-05-02 11:50:16,146 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Key:       ('drop_by_shallow_copy-a53d5051544bd753aba49ffa70f5d884', 2)
Function:  subgraph_callable-3a0eb9ed-37b3-48c6-84c0-718901bb
args:      (['_merge'], 'getitem-144883d72a7548ec872e0ea6c665ac0f',         adv_record_id                     event_time  ...                                              email                                              phone
0    811dd263d561f8e8  2023-01-03 02:51:37.056471220  ...  384c40e0fd1440824a0e673992948aa3f8a80aa4e9cda1...  98c209e1844571feb3090e49aac5131dd77a73978088f4...
1    dca2a7ba37819a82  2023-01-07 12:17:03.203660214  ...  762c4ba9be071dcaf990974921a7c7d77ada45839ce60c...  4d3edd12ab6691fab312cdd7c6092d84fd3e2a42cf42b5...
2    c84837de699dba55  2023-01-06 05:45:14.249238980  ...  456a56b276926aa0da22f90dc4bdf37242a3488508aca0...  439d65b8c7cdcb74d1e095bec8a33cbdb3b6233a3a4283...
3    a69a33a5a01916ff  2023-01-07 10:33:53.657674239  ...  6dcd2fd775ad57fea08fa2bcd1f5e8414ca9387d275a15...  b5303cdaab2d1fce608c2bd96a8bdb8b576bcf70d9c96d...
4    7205b56ef8d8d543  2023-01-02 14:51:58.300779686  ...  096be3ce2ff6f13ed3e94d675c629e65f9ceba03e4443b...  d82d20b1987e0bdead20946093b3c60e4
kwargs:    {}
Exception: "KeyError('_merge')"

Is there a way to restrict Dask to not emit contents of the dataframe when it crashes?
I read through https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/debug.html and I don't see any option to just restrict emitting dataframe output. I could presumably restrict the verbosity of ALL logs by package, but I would still like to see stack traces, ideally.
